# ASP.NET MVC 5, Using ADMembershipProvider via Form Authentication shows me as always Logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, membership-provider

I'm possibly missing something here because after setting up `Web.config` and my `Controller` to use `ADMembershipProvider`, Even with `Global Filters` for `[Authorize]` I'm always logged-in... I stepped through the code and noticed the following:

**Screenshot from Layout**
[image]

I'm connected to Corp domain, but my goal is to use Form Auth so that user need to Login with their AD Credentials and not auto authenticate; which seems to be the case.

[UPDATE]
I disconnected my WIFI and the application still shows me that I'm Authenticated, I also attempted this in Private/Incognito Mode and no luck.

[UPDATE 2]
I forgot to mention a very important aspect of my front end, Its all Angular. The way I'm doing this is, Controller responds with the View. Once the view loads angular kicks in and downloads what is needed via `$http.get` or `$http.post`. I notice that the page renders fine but certain parts give me error at random times. For example I wen't to access a page and it loaded fine but the dropdown boxes didn't populate and when I looked closely at the data coming in it was the login page.. So it was attempting to redirect me.. How do i handle this? If thats the case?

**Web.config**

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="45" slidingExpiration="false" protection="All" />
    </authentication>
    <membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
  </system.web>
```

**My Account Controller**

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return this.View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return this.View(model);
            }

            try
            {
                if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);

                    return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Fails if connection with LDAP can't be established.
                this.ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Internal Server Error, please check your Internet Connection. Unable to connect to Network!");
            }

            this.ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");

            return this.View(model);
        }

        public ActionResult LogOff()
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

            return this.RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think your problem is the .SetAuthCookie? Did you already tried to start an 'in private' browser session?

Comment: Tried it in private mode, still goes through. Also, disconnected WIFI (not in corp network anymore and it still goes through.) Hm.

Comment: Please try and replace [AllowAnonymous] ->  [Authorize]

Comment: That's the Login page, I Don't need `[Authorize]` there.. That controller needs to be available to anonymous requests in order for them to Login. Anyways I went ahead and replaced it with  `[Authorize]` , Didn't make a Difference.

Comment: What you mean by `Global Auth`?

Comment: I meant `Global Action Filters`, In this case the `[Authorize]` attribute. I went ahead and updated my question.

Comment: Does it happen when you change the membership provider to any other custom provider?

Comment: @Wiktor sorry for the delay. Yes it does behave the same but I did notice something last night. My app has an ASP.NET MVC Backend with an Angular front end. At times when I do a GET request I'm getting back the login page as response and i'm attempting to parse as JSON so i get error, it doesn't always happen which is a bit misleading. I will update my question with this information.

Comment: It's almost like you had TWO web apps, one uses forms auth, the other windows integrated auth.

Comment: @Wiktor Still no luck here... I even tested this in another system with fresh Windows 7 Pro install. It continues to tell me that I'm always authorized as the local account which is the account running IISExpress. I edited the config file for my IISExpress (`applicationhoist.config`) and enabled `iisClientCertificationMappingAuthentication` made sure `windowsAuthentication` was set to `false`..

Comment: That's really odd, I would expect you having trouble making Windows authentication working but not the opposite. What if you move the site to IIS? Also, what if you call it from another machine (not locally)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was `windowsAuthentication` being on by default in `IIS Express`.

After testing this in a fresh Windows 7 Pro 64bit Install, I noticed that when I debugged the app it asked for username and password, for some reason this did not come up in my main machine (maybe it was stored?)

[image]

So I use my standard windows login credentials and was able to get to the page. This explains why `@User.Identity.IsAuthorize` always shows true, Its using my Local computer account to authenticate me. After researching this issue a bit longer I've found how to remove that and just enable `anonymousAuthentication`.

```
<authentication>
    <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
    <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
</authentication>
```

I found [KB-837139](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837139) which goes into detail on how to disable this.

> **How to use Internet Services Manager to disable Integrated Windows
>   authentication in IIS 7.0**
>
> - Start Internet Services Manager.
> - Expand the server that contains the    Web site, the virtual directory, or the file for which you want to    configure
>     authentication, and then expand Sites.
> - In the console tree, click the Web site or the virtual directory for which you want to configure authentication.
> - In the center window frame, double-click Authentication.
> - In the list of authentication types, right-click Windows Authentication, and then click Disable
> - Exit Internet Services Manager.

In my case, I had to do it manually by going to the `applicationhost.config` which is located in `C:\Users\UserAccount\Documents\IISExpress\config` and opening up the file. I found it easier to load this up in Visual Studio and `Toggle all Outlining`. Then i found the following section and manually made the changes.

```
<location path="YourProjectNameIsHere">
        <system.webServer>
            <security>
                <authentication>
                    <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
                    <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
                </authentication>
            </security>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
```